# Apply each row of column 2 to each row of column 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I am simply trying to concatenate two columns together to come up with every possible combination of concatenations of the two columns. Column 1 would look like this:

| Origin |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

Column 2 would look like this:

| Destination |
| --- |
| X |
| Y |
| Z |

I need to come up with every combination of the two columns joined, to look like this:

| Origin | Destination |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| A | Y |
| A | Z |
| B | X |
| B | Y |
| B | Z |
| C | X |
| C | Y |
| C | Z |

I have this roughly 2000 rows in each column, so copy and pasting is simply not going to work. I have used SQL in the past to join two columns to get a result of only the matching values from each table, but this is looking for all combinations.

Comment: `from table1 cross join table2`??

Comment: Wow. Feeling dumb! That was very easy, thank you!

Comment: That's ok, you can always learn, need to start somewhere (although Googling may have helped). It was just a "I'm not sure what you meant, as it seemed to easy for me, so maybe I'm misreading"

Answer (score 1):

```
declare
    @t table (A varchar (10), B varchar (10))

insert into @t
select 'A', 'X'
union all
select 'B', 'Y'
union all
select 'C', 'Z'

select t2.A,t.B from @t t
cross join @t t2
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.